# Decrypt shared library in memory at run-time in Android

Tags: android, encryption, shared-libraries

Can we load an encrypted .so library and decrypt in real-time in memory to use it?

So for example, I have an Android app signature, as possibly everyone that released a public app does. I also have in an app I'm making, a shared library (.so file) that I made. The idea would be that I could encrypt that .so file with some encryption key and then decrypt the file using the current APK signature, which can be gotten easily.

Someone modifies the APK file, someone's screwed, unless they steal my signature from my personal files and such, since that library won't work at all and part of the app will not work. Is this possible?

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:** after the chat with CommonsWare, solutions seem to be Java check code for APK signature, or the libraries checking for the signature, and in case the APK is modified, the libraries stop working and only part of the app works (not perfect, of course - reverse-engineering -, but better than nothing, maybe).

Comment: Note that what you describe (dynamically loading native code) is banned by the Play Store and possibly by other app distribution channels. Moreover, any developer who is able to modify your APK file is also able to copy the decrypted `.so` file, after you have decrypted it.

Comment: But if you modify the APK, the signature changes, and you could no longer decrypt the .so file, which would be stored encrypted inside the APK (like it's done normally, but instead, encrypted). Unless one can get the APK signature externally outside the app... Didn't think on that. Is that possible? Also about the PlayStore part, thank you for the warning! Still though, I could use the idea (if it works) in a release outside PlayStore.

Comment: "But if you modify the APK, the signature changes, and you could no longer decrypt the .so file, which would be stored encrypted inside the APK" -- if they can modify the APK, they can modify the APK to use the decrypted `.so` file, by simply removing the "decrypt" part.

Comment: But where would they get the decrypted .so file from, if I'm storing it encrypted in the APK and never decrypted? (Maybe I'm missing something here?)

Comment: " if I'm storing it encrypted in the APK and never decrypted?" -- if you are never decrypting it, then the `.so` is pointless, as it can never be used. It will need to be decrypted for the CPU to execute the instructions inside of the `.so`. Besides, your question states that you intend to decrypt it.

Comment: Yes, but as I said, I wanted to decrypt it in memory and it would stay only in memory and never in a form of a file (safer) - if Android can deal with this, which I don't know at all. In form of a file, if you prefer, only the encrypted version. The decrypted one only in memory. Who would want the decrypted version would have to exploit something to get stuff from memory. Btw, the "never decrypted" part, sorry for the confusion, I meant never *storing* the decrypted version.

Comment: "I wanted to decrypt it in memory" -- correct. And if your code is able to decrypt it, so too can other code, as both the decryption algorithm and the decryption key are available for anyone to see. You think that your decryption key is somehow tied to the APK itself, when, in reality, it is just a series of bytes. Anybody can use that series of bytes to decrypt the `.so` content. Your approach might stymie some intro-level script kiddies. Anybody who really wants to get at your app logic can do so.

Comment: Well, then there goes the idea... Pity haha. Was liking it xd. If it was hard to get the APK signature (like, you had to calculate something, no idea), I guess it could work better, since yes, the algorithm would be there, but the key would be harder (or not even that would work, no idea). The main idea was to use as decryption key, something that was only in a non-modified APK. If it was modified, the key would cease to exist there. So I thought on the APK signature. Well, back to the Java verification code which will just stop automatic apps (or maybe I don't use anything at all). Thank you!